# If $A$ and $B$ anti-commute then $A$ and $B^2 $ commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is this problem, which I tried to solve for long enough, and I want to know how even to start with this kind of problem:

\begin{align}  AB+BA=0 \Rightarrow A,B^2 \text{  commute.} \end{align}

Comment: Taking determinants $\det(BA)=(-1)^n\det(AB)$. If $n$ is odd then one of the matrices is singular, which is a contradiction of your premise.

Comment: So you're saying that $AB=BA$. The right term is that $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: The question now is: If $AB=-BA$, then $AB^2=B^2A$ ???

Answer (score 3):

If $AB=-BA$, then (multiplying both sides by $B$ on the right) $AB^2=-BAB$

and (multiplying both sides by $-B$ on the left) $-BAB=B^2A$,

so $AB^2=B^2A$; i.e., $A$ and $B^2$ **commute**.

Answer (score 0):

Use $[B^2,\,A]=[B,\,\{A,\,B\}]$.